# Text Field as Google autocompelete place api in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, google-places-api, uisearchbar

I want to create a screen like the image(image link provided) above.

[image]

If the "Posts","Foodies" , "Recipe" & "Blog" is selected ,the the text field (Discover & Search) will work as text field but when "Restaurant" & "Grocery Store " are selected then the text field will work as google autocomplete place api field . the text field (Bhubaneswar , India) ,is for location .

Any suggestion ,how to create this type of screen

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking is this [ios_google_places_autocomplete](https://github.com/varun-naharia/ios_google_places_autocomplete)

Comment: I already have tried this . but when i am selecting any place from the list , i want this place will be written on the text field(Discover & Search).so that i can search for this place easily. but when i am selecting any place it only dismisses the view.

Comment: can i take two search bar in place of text fields ?

Comment: the design you are showing is for android in ios every search activate search bar and when search completed result is send back to text field that activated search bar, So left it as it is and use same search for both textfield